# Filter SQL query condition for purchase with refund id

Tags: mysql

I have a data table which has two transaction types 'purchase' and 'refund' which has unique transaction id.

refund has another column named 'Refund ID' which is actually a transaction id for particular purchase. (let say there is a purchase with transaction id 100, so for refund the transaction id will be 101 and Refund ID will be 100).

Now in my query I want to show only the transaction type purchase but I want to add one field that if the particular purchase has been refunded it should show as refunded, if not refunded yet, the column should be null.

The query I have written is to display the data is:

```
SELECT Transaction_ID, Amount, Transaction_Type, Transaction_Date, Refund_ID
FROM Transaction 
WHERE Transaction_Status = 'OK'
ORDER BY Transaction_Date desc
```

Comment: Can you post your table structure and some sample data set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood your table have these 4 main columns -
t_id, t_type, amount, r_id.

According to me you need to add another column - 'refund status'(r_status). It can only have three values - "N.A" for transaction type purchase. "Refunded" and "null" for transaction type refund.
[image: For this table-]
Now, you want to display only details of transactions where transaction type is purchase along with refund status. The query for that is -

SELECT (@a:=t_id) as tr_id,(select if(t_id=(SELECT @b:=r_id from transaction where t_id>@a LIMIT 1),(select r_status from transaction where r_id=@b),'N.A')) as refund_status from transaction WHERE t_type="purchase"

If might be a little confusing. Let me explain, it will first select transaction id and also store it in 'a', then it will select refund status by checking if transaction id of current row is equal to the refund id of next row,if yes it will display the refund status of the refund id and if not it will show N.A .

[image: This is the result of query]

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exact how I wanted it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE WHEN` to check this.

```
SELECT Transaction_ID, Amount, Transaction_Type, Transaction_Date, Refund_ID,
       CASE WHEN IFNULL(Refund_ID, '') <> ''
       THEN 'Refunded'
       ELSE NULL
       END AS RefundStatus
FROM Transaction 
WHERE Transaction_Status = 'OK'
ORDER BY Transaction_Date desc
```

Comment: @Rudra Sorry about that, can you try the latest edit?